# Problems altering axis label font sizes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graphic

I have effectively a very simple question.

I am using ggplot2 code to alter the font size of axis text and labels. However, wherever I position the command, none of the changes are visible on the axes. All other commands are working, so I am getting the impression that something is 'overriding' the theme(axis.text..., axis.title...) command.

```
 ggplot(Cannock, aes(x=Capacity,color=CPType)) + 
   geom_histogram(fill="white",position="identity",binwidth=3,lwd=1) + 
   labs(title="Cannock Chase",x="Capacity", y = "Count") + 
   theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) + 
   facet_grid(CPType ~ .) + 
   geom_vline(data=mu1, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=CPType), linetype="dashed",size=1) + 
   theme_bw() + 
   theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()) + 
   theme(legend.position="none") + 
   theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size=8, fac[![enter image description here][1]][1]e="bold"), strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white")) + 
   coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100)) + 
   theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

Any pointers for this would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: That is strange.  Could you post your data or a sample so we can fool around with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be that you've called `theme_bw()` after you change your axis text formatting. Any formatting that you want to change from defaults needs to be changed after calling `theme_bw`. Additionally, just to be a little cleaner and tighter, you can combine all of your `theme` arguments into one group so that it's easier to keep track of what you're changing. Does the code below solve the problem?

You also specify `strip.text` and `strip.background` twice, with different settings, which is probably not what you want to do.

```
ggplot(Cannock, aes(x=Capacity,color=CPType)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill="white",position="identity",binwidth=3,lwd=1) + 
  labs(title="Cannock Chase",x="Capacity", y = "Count") + 
  facet_grid(CPType ~ .) + 
  geom_vline(data=mu1, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=CPType), linetype="dashed",size=1) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=8, face="bold"), 
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```